# how to display only description in wordpress home page

Tags: wordpress, post

I am using wordpress for my blog.
I used the some pluging to add meta data for each post.

Whenever I add the new post, the home page displaying entire article. Instead of that I want to display only description or small portion of the article in the home page.

Could anyone help me how to display description of the post only in home page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use more tags or use excerpt in wordpress

Comment: can you share plugin code how plugin call it
or what plugin use `get_posts` function or `wp_query_post` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the more tag, as simple as that. Read more: http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.php` (also could be in a separate file like, loop-content or so if your template used [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function), there is a function call, like

```
the_content()
```

just change it to

```
the_excerpt();
```

and you are done. Read more [on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt).

Comment: @Raj, Welcome and if it solves your problem then you should accept the answer by clicking the tick beneath my answer, make it green and you can accept only one answer for a question, I think you don't know that.